# iPhone 6 and its 750x1334px and two UIButtons in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone-6

With the iPhone 6 and its 750x1334 px (375x667 px non-retina), how is it possible to put two UIButtons next to each other with both the same width on a UIView (see attached image) ?

It was always really easy on the others iPhones (<= 5S) but with this odd width, it's not possible, no ? I really don't get how to build it on Interface Builder (with or without Autolayout).

[image: I would have this but with same width, like on iPhone 5S]

Comment: you can do it through Autolayout

Comment: Could you explain how you do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I give you link you  can try this example in your apps may be help full for you

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/size-classes-ios8-xcode-6

Comment: Thank you. I'used Autolayout and it works. It's just a little bit difficult in the beggining.

Comment: Welcome I Accept in starting stage some problem you faced